# Find if this series is convergent or divergent: $\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\dots+\sqrt[m]{m}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find if this series converges or diverges.

The ratio test gives me limit 1 so I tried with Raabe Duhamel's test but I am stuck .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETKSt.png

$$\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\dots+\sqrt[m]{m}}$$

Comment: $n^{1/n}< 2$; use the Comparison Test.

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{2*n} < x_n $$ therefore the series is divergent?

Comment: Good tool for numerical testing: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w5cqiyokhp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491213/convergence-or-divergence-of-sum-n-in-mathbbn-left-sum-k-1n-k)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt[m]{m} < 2\ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now you have 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \sqrt[k]{k} < \sum\limits_{k=1}^m 2 = 2m$$
Therefore
$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \sqrt[k]{k}} > \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2m} = \infty$$
Thus the series diverges.

**Note:** Induction or applying the binomial theorem for $(1+1)^m$ gives you $m<2^m$ and therefore $\sqrt[m]{m} < 2$