# Examine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{1/k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I know that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^{1/n}}$$ diverges, since the limit when $n$ tends to infinity of $n^\frac{1}{n}$ is equal to $1$.
With this, I cannot conclude anything about the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{1/k}}$$
I don't see how to apply the root test, and I don't know which series I should choose to apply the comparison test. If I apply the Cauchy Condensation test we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}k^{1/k}}$$ and i don't know how to solve that limit

Comment: do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{1/k}}$?

Comment: I want to write this: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+n^1/2+...+n^1/n}$$.

Comment: it is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^{1/k}}$ then.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3429545/42969