# How do you evaluate the limit of this sequence involving n-th roots?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, products

This is the limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\cdot\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}...\sqrt[2n]{2n}
\end{equation}
I tried to rearrange the terms to apply the geometric mean theorem but my attempt was not successful. Any way to solve this will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=n}^{2n}\sqrt[k]k=e^{\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\ln{k}}{k}}>e^{\ln{n}\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}}=n\cdot e^{\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}}\rightarrow+\infty$$ because $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{0}{n}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+...+\frac{1}{1+\frac{n}{n}}\right)\frac{1}{n}=$$
$$=\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln(1+x)|_0^1=\ln2.$$

Comment: Quite an elegant solution. Just out of curiosity, was I supposed to know the last identity from undegrad Real Analysis (only for single variable functions)?

Comment: @Feynman_00   We can prove it by the definition of the Riemann's integral. If you want I am ready to show.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you did (if the rules allow it).

Comment: @Feynman_00 I added something. See now.

Comment: I understand. The only integral definition I was given was Darboux integral that only involves supremum of inferior sum and infimum of superior sum. Riemann's limit definition is quite useful, I'll study something about it.

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$\sqrt[n]{n}\cdot\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}...\sqrt[2n]{2n}=e^{\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}}$$

and by this result

- [Big $\mathcal{O}$ Notation question while estimating $\sum \frac{\log n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13300/505767)

we obtain

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\log k}{k} =\frac{(\log 2n)^2}{2}-\frac{(\log (n-1))^2}{2} + O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)$$

with

$$(\log 2n)^2-(\log (n-1))^2=\left(\log \left(\frac{2n}{n-1}\right)\right)(\log (2n(n-1)) \to \infty$$

---

More simply we have

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k} \ge n \cdot \frac{\log (2n)}{2n}=\frac{\log (2n)}{2} $$

and therefore

$$e^{\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}} \ge e^{\frac{\log (2n)}{2}}\to \infty$$

Comment: I like this solution as well. Once again, as I said above those sums and big $\mathcal{O}$ are quite new to me, so (just out of curiosity) was I supposed to know that from an undegrad real analysis course?

Comment: @Feynman_00 Yes in same cases it is a very useful notation to simplify the presentation and I suppose it should be covered in any real analysis course.

Comment: @Feynman_00 In this case, following the idea from other answers, we can obtain the result by simpler considerations. I've added a solution using that way.

Answer (score 4):

Factor out $n$ from each of the $n$ factors on the right, to obtain $$n^{1/n+1/(n+1)+1/(n+2)+\cdots+1/2n}\left(1+\frac1 n\right)^{1/(n+1)}\left(1+\frac1 n\right)^{1/(n+2)}\cdots\left(1+\frac1 n\right)^{1/2n},$$ which makes the limit at $n=\infty$ clear.

Comment: Each terms tends to $1$ therefore it is not so clear how to determine the limit. Maybe you could add something more on that.

Comment: @user All factors, *except for the first,* get arbitrarily close to $1$ at $n=\infty.$ Obviously, the first becomes unbounded, since the exponent is harmonic.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't read properly your first step. Now it is clear to me. Thanks