# Does this series of primes converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

> Denote the prime numbers $2,3,5,7,\ldots$ as $p_1,p_2,\ldots$. Determine whether the infinite series $\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}+\dfrac{p_3}{p_4}+\cdots = \dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{5}{7}+\cdots$ converges.

I was wondering about this question because we can't really use the ratio test here because the ratio is constantly changing. So how would we determine if the series converges or not?

Answer (score 8):

By Bertrand's Postulate (a theorem since the mid nineteeth century) there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$. As a consequence, $p_{2k-1}/p_{2k}$ does not have limit $0$, so the series cannot converge.

Comment: There's a much easier proof: the answer I've posted here. (Proving Bertrand's postulate takes some work.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I agree that the argument that uses the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{p_k}$ is substantially more elementary.

Comment: As $n$ gets larger, so does the gap between $n$ and $2n$. So how does that prove the sequence doesn't have limit $0$?

Comment: Let $n=p_{2k-1}$. Even if we interpret the Bertrand Postulate weakly, the prime $p_{2k}$ is $\lt 4p_{2k-1}$, so the ratio is $\gt \frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 4):

It diverges.
\begin{align}
\frac{p_1}{p_2} + \frac{p_3}{p_4} + \cdots \ge \frac 1 {p_2} + \frac 1 {p_4} + \cdots & = \frac 1 2 \left( \frac 2 {p_2} + \frac 2 {p_4} + \cdots \right) \\[10pt]
& \ge \frac 1 2 \left( \left( \frac 1 {p_2} + \frac 1 {p_3} \right) + \left( \frac 1 {p_4} + \frac 1 {p_5} \right) + \cdots \right) \\[10pt]
& = \infty.
\end{align}

Comment: Why does $\left( \left( \frac{1}{p_2} + \frac{1}{p_3} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{p_4} + \frac{1}{p_5} \right) + \cdots \right)$ diverge to infinity?

Comment: @JacobWillis : Maybe you should post that as a separate question.  Suppose $A\subseteq\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\sum\limits_{n\in A} \dfrac 1 n<\infty$ then $\sum\limits_{n\in B} \dfrac 1 n <\infty$ where $B$ is the closure of $A$ under multiplication.  The closure of the set of primes under multiplication is all of $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, and the sum of the reciprocals of those diverges to $\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @JacobWillis : That question has been posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @JacobWillis : I've just added [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge/1603524#1603524) to your question in your comment above. ${}\qquad{}$