# Show that the series $\sum_\text{p prime}\frac{1}{p}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that the series $$\sum_\text{p prime}\frac{1}{p}$$ is divergent.

I know that $\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p}$ is a p-series with $p=1$, it is a Harmonic series and is divergent, but in this case $p$ are only the prime numbers. Is it still valid?

Comment: No, the same proof as used for the harmonic series is not valid for this problem.  See [the wikipedia article on this sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) and similar questions on this site [such as this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge).

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate.