# sum of the reciprocal of the prime factors of a square free number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-sum

Let $n$ an odd square free number, and $p_1, \ldots , p_n$ their distinct prime factors. Ir is true that
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i} < 1? $$

Otherwise, there exists some conditions to ensure that this works?

Comment: perfect numbers ...

Comment: Is it on purpose that $n$ is the same number as the number of the prime factors of $n$ (there is no such number, so the statement would be true)? Otherwise, then the sum doesn't have to be less than $1$ (indeed, consider the product of the first $n$ prime numbers)

Comment: Take $n=30=2\times 3\times 5$.  Note that $\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 15=\frac {31}{30}$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean an odd number  Typo fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge), thus the answer to your question is No.

Mind you, it diverges very slowly.  The first odd counterexample is $$N= 3234846615=3\times  5\times 7\times 11\times 13\times 17\times 19\times 23\times 29 $$

For that number, the sum comes to just over $1$ (see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5Bsum%5B1%2Fprime%5Bn%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C2%2C10%7D%5D%5D)). But don't let the slow speed of divergence fool you.  If you put in enough primes you can make the sum as large as you want.