# Is it true that $\prod_{i=1}^n\left(3 + \frac{1}{3i}\right) < \left(3 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, products

I am still scratching my head trying to develop my intuition about products of simple sums.

Is it true that:

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{3i}\right) < \left(3 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

It seems to me that this is true.

For $n = 1, 2, 3$, $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{3i}\right) - \left(3 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$, the difference increases as $n$ increases.

Am I right?  What approach should I take in this case to find a counter example or to confirm that the difference is continuously increasing as $n$ increases?

Comment: For large $n$, the product is $\sim C\,n^{1/9}\,3^n$, while the power is $\sim e^{1/3}\,3^n$.

Comment: Wow,  So, if I'm understanding correctly, at larger $n$, the relationship breaks down.  Thanks very much!  How did you arrive at these estimates?

Comment: Yes, indeed. For $n=10$, your inequality is still true, but for $n=20$, it isn't. $n^{1/9}$ isn't growing very quickly, that's why the first few terms give the wrong impression.

Comment: Thanks!  Very educational!

Comment: @LarryFreeman For the right side, you have $\left(3 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 3^n\left(1 + \frac{(1/3)}{n}\right)^n$. As shown at the end of the [Formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) section, you get that, as $n \to \infty$, the part in the brackets approaches $e^x$ with $x = \frac{1}{3}$ so, as Professor Vector's comment states, your right side value is asymptotically similar to $e^{1/3}3^n$.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnOmielan.  This is great!  Lots to learn.  The Wikipedia article is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the gamma function$$P_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{3i}\right)=\frac{3^n\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{10}{9}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)
   \Gamma (n+1)}$$ Taking its logarithm, using Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor expansion, we have
$$\log(P_n)=n \log(3)+\frac 19\log(n)-\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)\right)+\frac 5{81n}+O\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)$$

Doing the same for

$$Q_n=\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

$$\log(Q_n)=n \log (3)+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{18 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

$$\log(Q_n)-\log(P_n)=-\frac{\log (n)}{9}+\frac{1}{3}+\log \left(\Gamma
   \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)\right)-\frac{19}{162 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\frac {Q_n}{P_n}=e^{\log(Q_n)-\log(P_n)}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{e} (162 n-19) \Gamma \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)}{162 n^{10/9}}$$ and, according to this approximation $\frac {Q_n}{P_n} < 1$ as soon as $n>9$.

It is quite inaccurate and we need more terms for a better bound; Adding two terms to the expansion shows that it *could* be true for $n > 11$.

Now, it is time for numerical checks (the numbers are rounded to the closest integer)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & P_n & Q_n \\
 10 & 81025 & 81963 \\
 11 & 245529 & 246008 \\
 12 & 743407 & 738322 \\
 13 & 2249282 & 2215727 \\
 14 & 6801399 & 6649146 \\
 15 & 20555340 & 19952558
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach which uses a couple of properties of the prime numbers. First, as discussed in the question comments, e.g., with [Professor Vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436658/professor-vector)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844513/reasoning-about-products-of-decreasing-terms#comment7930473_3844513), the right hand side of your inequality is

$$f(n) = \left(3 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 3^n\left(1 + \frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{n}\right)^n \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As shown at the end of the [Formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) section of Wikipedia's "Exponential function" article,

$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

In your case, $x = \frac{1}{3}$, so for large $n$,

$$f(n) \sim 3^ne^{\frac{1}{3}} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

In particular, the limit existing means $\left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)^n$ is bounded, so there's a constant $C$ where, for all positive integers $n$,

$$f(n) \lt C(3^n) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

The left side of your inequality is

$$g(n) = \prod_{i=1}^n\left(3 + \frac{1}{3i}\right) = 3^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \frac{1}{9i}\right)\right) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Note

$$(1 + x_1)(1 + x_2) = 1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_1 x_2  \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

$$(1 + x_1)(1 + x_2)(1 + x_3) = 1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

In general, the product of $n$ factors $1 + x_i$ is the sum of all of the $x_i$ taken $0$ at a time (i.e., just $1$), $1$ at a time, $2$ at a time, etc., up to $n$ at a time. Thus, if all $x_i \ge 0$, they'll all be non-negative terms, so for all integers $n \ge 1$,

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{n}(1 + x_i)^n \gt \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Using this with the right side of \eqref{eq5A} gives

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1 + \frac{1}{9i}\right) \gt \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{9i}\right) \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

The [Prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) shows for large integers $m$,

$$p_m \sim m\ln(m) \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

This means there's an integer $m_0$ where, for all $m \ge m_0$,

$$p_m \gt 9m \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Thus, for any $n \ge m_0$,

$$\sum_{i=m_0}^n\left(\frac{1}{9i}\right) \gt \sum_{i=m_0}^n\left(\frac{1}{p_i}\right) \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

However, such as discussed in [Does the sum of reciprocals of primes converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15946/602049), and shown in Wikipedia's [Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) article, the right side of \eqref{eq12A} diverges. Thus, the left side must also diverge, so it'll eventually become larger than the $C$ in \eqref{eq4A}. This means there's an $n_0$ where, for all $n \ge n_0$,

$$g(n) \gt f(n) \tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

i.e., your inequality will not be true. Note this also shows that if you change the $\frac{1}{3i}$ in $g(n)$ defined in \eqref{eq5A} to instead be $\frac{1}{ki}$ for some positive constant $k$, then no matter how large $k$ is, your inequality will still always eventually no longer be true.

**Update:** The right side of \eqref{eq9A} is $\frac{1}{9}$ of the [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) which is known to diverge. Using this is simpler and more direct than utilizing the properties of the prime numbers I used above.

Comment: Thanks very much for these details!  It was $n^{\frac{1}{9}}$ that was  the most unclear up to now.  This greatly helps.