Show that the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{p_n}$ diverges with the help of a given inequality
Given the series $ \sum_n \frac 1 {p_n}, p\in \mathbb P $,  show that it diverges with the help of the inequality $ p_n < n \log n+n\log\log n,\, \forall n \ge 6.  $
Besides the inequality being an upper bound for the partial sums of the series I don't see how it can help me show anything, any ideas on how to tackle this problem or at least  where I should begin at.

$\frac{1}{p_n}  > \frac{1}{2 n \log n}$

Various proofs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

... and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15946/42969

Hint: $n\log(\log n) < n\log n$, and use the integral test !
