# How to estimate $\sum_{p\leqslant x}\sum_{q\leqslant x}\frac{1}{p+q}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

How to estimate $$\sum_{p\leqslant x}\sum_{q\leqslant x}\frac{1}{p+q}, \qquad\qquad(1)$$
where $p$, $q$ are prime numbers.

We have the Mertens' formula
$$ \sum_{p\leqslant x} \frac{1}{p} = \log\log x+ B + O\left( \frac{1}{\log x} \right),  $$
where $p$ is prime number, and $B=\gamma - \sum_{p} \left( \log \left( \frac{1}{1-1/p} \right) - \frac{1}{p} \right)$ is the Mertens constant, $\gamma$ is Euler constant.

I guess the main term of (1) is $\dfrac{x\log\log x}{\log x}$, but I don't prove it, Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, your sum (let's denote it $S$) satisfies
  $$ \frac x{2\log^2 x}\, (1+o(1)) \le S\le \frac{2x}{\log^2 x}\, (1+o(1)), \tag{$\ast$} $$
so that $x\log\log x/\log x$ cannot be the main term.

The upper bound is easy to prove observing that 
  $$ \frac1{p+q} \le \frac1{2\sqrt{pq}} $$
by the AM-GM  inequality. It follows that
  $$ S \le \frac12\,\sum_{p,q\le x} \frac1{\sqrt{pq}} = \frac12\left(\sum_{p\le x} \frac1{\sqrt p}\right)^2. $$
The sum in the RHS [is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12588) to satisfy
  $$ \sum_{p\le x} \frac1{\sqrt p} = \frac{2\sqrt x}{\log x}\,(1+o(1)). $$
Combining the last two estimates, we get the upper bound in ($\ast$).

For the lower bound, just notice that
  $$ S \ge \sum_{p,q\le x}\frac1{2x} = \frac{(\pi(x))^2}{2x} = \frac x{2\log^2 x}\, (1+o(1)) $$
by the prime number theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use the PNT then you need to provide the asymptotic, not only bounds @arithmetic1

Comment: @reuns: What do you mean "need"? I probably *can*, using partial summation; and I also can avoid using the PNT, but then the lower bound will be relaxed to $\Omega(x/\log^2(x))$.  But the OP was asking for an *estimate*, and have not indicated that he does not want to use the PNT, correct?

Comment: I find $\sum_{p\leqslant x}\sum_{q\leqslant x}\frac{1}{p+q}\sim\sum_{2\le n \le x}\sum_{2\le m \le x} \frac{1}{n+m} \frac{1}{\ln n\ \ln m}\sim \sum_{ n \le x}\sum_{ m \le x} \frac{1}{n+m} \frac{1}{\ln^2 x}$ $\sim \frac{1}{\ln^2 x}\sum_{l \le 2x} \frac{\min(l,x)}{l} \sim \frac{x (1+\ln 2)}{\ln^2 x}$

Comment: @reuns: Working out carefully the technical details can be quite messy, but if you are ready, you may consider adding another answer.